# How to resolve the error: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 code, I am trying to display the Line Manager of a Employee

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
    $linemanageruserid = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();

    $linemanageruserids = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $linemanageruserid->line_manager_id)->first();  

    $linemanagerdetails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id','employee_code','first_name','last_name')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();
    $linemanagerdetail = $linemanagerdetails->first_name . ' ' . $linemanagerdetails->last_name;

    $employees      =       HrEmployee::with('linemanager')->where('id', $userId)->get();
    return view('dashboard')
            ->with('employees', $employees)
            ->with('linemanagerdetail', $linemanagerdetail);   
}
```

view

```
     @foreach($employees as $key => $employee)
    <!-- Profile Image -->
    <div class="card card-secondary card-outline">
      <div class="card-body box-profile">

        <h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{auth()->user()->first_name}} {{auth()->user()->last_name}}</h3>

        <p class="text-muted text-center">Designation: {{isset($employee->designation) ? $employee->designation->designation_name : 'N/A'}}</p>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered mb-3">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <b>Staff ID:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->employee_code) ? $employee->employee_code : 'N/A'}}</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <b>Department:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->department) ? $employee->department->dept_name : 'N/A'}}</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <b>Grade Level:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($employee->gradelevel) ? $employee->gradelevel->grade_level_name : 'N/A'}}</a>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <b>Line Manager:</b> <a class="float-right">{{isset($linemanagerdetail) ? $linemanagerdetail : 'None'}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
      <!-- /.card-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
    @endforeach
```

When I rendered the view, I expected

> {{isset($linemanagerdetail) ? $linemanagerdetail : 'None'}}

to display line manager's first_name and last_name, but I got thus error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Then this line of code is highlighted:

> $linemanagerdetails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id','employee_code','first_name','last_name')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();

When I debugged, I observed that the error occurred because the field is null.

How do I display None if the field is null?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you're not logged in and ``Auth::user()`` returns null? Otherwise there's something wrong with your queries in lines 7-13. Try to figure out what they return using ``dd()``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely that `$linemanageruserids` is not an object, but is instead an array where you'll need to use `$linemanageruserids['id']`.

This is because a `DB::table(...)` call can't return an object since it has no way of knowing how to cast the results. Hence, it will return an array of arrays. By then calling `first()` on the call, you just a get a single dimension array as a result.

Hope that explains things!